# Categorise JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, graphql

Hey please don't roast me. So i have a JSON data like this

```
data": {
    "person": [
      {
        "id": "xx1",
        "name": "John DOe",
      },
     ],
    "person": [
      {
        "id": "xx2",
        "name": "John Snow",
      },
     ],
}
```

For example, I want to store every person data whose name contains "o". How could I do that? Thank you

Comment: use `array.filter` function

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service, what have you tried already? What is your expected result from sample input? BTW I don't think your `data` is valid object, you've duplicate `person` keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON object ,if have duplicate keys, it will replace the first one with the most bottom one .

In your sample data, there is two "person" keys. Therefore, at the end, your said data will succumb to this.

```
{"data":{"person":[{"id":"xx2","name":"John Snow"}]}}
```

Therefore, to clarify your data, IMHO, this is supposed to be like this in the first place.

```
"data": {
    "person": [
      {
        "id": "xx1",
        "name": "John DOe",
      },
      {
        "id": "xx2",
        "name": "John Snow",
      },
     ]
}
```

Then you can treat `data.person` as an array and use **Array.prototype** function to `filter` out your desired details.

The filter method should be

```
const personWithNameO = data.person.filter((v) => v.name.includes("o") );
console.log(personWithNameO);
```

Comment: thank you soo much! you really help me man :) hope u have a good life